# Resize an Image with Javascript Incode LogicApps

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to use the `Incode` functionality to resize an image in LogicApps.
I'm not sure if this is possible with the absence of HTML.

```
var inputImage = workflowContext.actions.GetFileContent.outputs.body.$content;
function resize_image(imagesrc)
{
    let image = new Image();
    var base = "data:image/png;base64,";
        image.src = base.concat(imagesrc);
image.onload = () => {
            let width = image.width;
            let height = image.height;
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = newWidth ;
            canvas.height = newHeight;

            let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            context.drawImage(image, 450, 0, newWidth-500, newHeight);
}
return image;
}
return resize_image(inputImage);
```

The error I receive

```
The inline code action 'JavaScriptCode' execution failed, with error 'Image is not defined'.
```

`$content` is the image in Base64, for example, starts like this:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACFwAAAMMCAYAAABkSiF3...
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline code can only perform some simple JavaScript operations, it may not be able to install `canvas`.

You can create an [Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-get-started?pivots=programming-language-csharp) to resize your image.

For more details, you can refer to [Call functions from Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps).

Comment: Thanks, yes I wanted to avoid that but you are right, even if I'm able to run canvas it should be in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the question. I realized is not feasible talking with Javascript developers. They estimated a running time of 3 or 4 seconds, pretty close to the 5-second mark.